# asyncio Add Callback after Task is completed, instead of asyncio.as_completed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

In `asyncio`, it there a way to attach a callback function to a `Task` such that this callback function will run after the `Task` has been completed?

So far, the only way I can figure out is to use `asyncio.completed` in a loop, as shown below. But this requires 2 lists (`tasks` and `cb_tasks`) to hold all the tasks/futures.

Is there a better way to do this?

```py
import asyncio
import random


class Foo:
    async def start(self):
        tasks = []
        cb_tasks = []

        # Start ten `do_work` tasks simultaneously
        for i in range(10):
            task = asyncio.create_task(self.do_work(i))
            tasks.append(task)
            # How to run `self.handle_work_done` as soon as this `task` is completed?

        for f in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
            res = await f
            t = asyncio.create_task(self.work_done_cb(res))
            cb_tasks.append(t)

        await asyncio.wait(tasks + cb_tasks)

    async def do_work(self, i):
        """ Simulate doing some work """
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        await asyncio.sleep(x)
        print(f"Finished work #{i}")
        return x

    async def work_done_cb(self, x):
        """ Callback after `do_work` has been completed """
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))
        print(f"Finished additional work {x}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    asyncio.run(foo.start())
```

Comment: Have you already tried [`add_done_callback(callback, *, context=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/asyncio-future.html#asyncio.Future.add_done_callback)?

Comment: Any feedback please?

Comment: @Timus Looks like what I was looking for! Between`add_done_callback` and `asyncio.as_completed`, is one generally better than the other?